# dictionary add values for the same keys

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.6

I have a list of dictionary:

```
[{'name':'Jay', 'value':'1'},{'name':'roc', 'value':'9'},{'name':'Jay', 'value':'7'},{'name':'roc', 'value':'2'}]
```

I want it to be:

```
[{'name':'Jay', 'value':'8'},{'name':'roc', 'value':'11'}]
```

I tried looping through but I am not able to find an example where I can do this. Any hint or idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a *defaultdict*:

```
lst = [{'name':'Jay', 'value':'1'},{'name':'roc', 'value':'9'},{'name':'Jay', 'value':'7'},{'name':'roc', 'value':'2'}]
```

1) sum values for each name:

```
from collections import defaultdict    
result = defaultdict(int)

for d in lst:
    result[d['name']] += int(d['value'])
```

2) convert the name-value pair to a dictionary within a list:

```
[{'name': name, 'value': value} for name, value in result.items()]
# [{'name': 'roc', 'value': 11}, {'name': 'Jay', 'value': 8}]
```

Or if you want the value as str type as commented by @Kevin:

```
[{'name': name, 'value': str(value)} for name, value in result.items()]
​# [{'name': 'roc', 'value': '11'}, {'name': 'Jay', 'value': '8'}]
```

Comment: Nice solution. OP may want to instead do `'value': str(value)` in the final expression, depending on whether they want to mirror the typing of the original dict.

Comment: Yeap I agree with @Kevin I will change it to str. Thank you, it works I will accept answer soon due to time limit :)

Comment: `collections.Counter` can be a nice alternative too.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Indeed. You might make an answer to show how it works?

Comment: @Psidom if you insist :) very similar to yours though.

Answer (score 3):

This is a good use case for `itertools.groupby`.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

orig = [{'name':'Jay', 'value':'1'},
        {'name':'roc', 'value':'9'},
        {'name':'Jay', 'value':'7'},
        {'name':'roc', 'value':'2'}]

get_name = itemgetter('name')
result = [{'name': name, 'value': str(sum(int(d['value']) for d in dicts))}
           for name, dicts in groupby(sorted(orig, key=get_name), key=get_name)]
```

Breaking it down:

1. `get_name` is a function that given a dictionary, returns the value of its "name" key. I.e., `get_name = lambda x: x['name']`.
2. `sorted` returns the list of dictionaries sorted by the value of the `"name"` key.
3. `groupby` returns an iterator of `(name, dicts)` where `dicts` is a list (ok, generator) of the dicts that share `name` as the value of the `"name"` key. (Grouping only occurs for consecutive items with the same key value, hence the need to sort the list in the previous step.)
4. The result is a list of new dictionaries using the given name and the *sum* of all the related `"value"` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Psidom's answer but using `collections.Counter` which is the perfect candidate for accumulating integer values.

```
import collections

d =[{'name':'Jay', 'value':'1'},{'name':'roc', 'value':'9'},{'name':'Jay', 'value':'7'},{'name':'roc', 'value':'2'}]

c = collections.Counter()
for sd in d:
    c[sd["name"]] += int(sd["value"])
```

Then, you need to rebuild the dicts if needed, by converting back to string.

```
print([{"name":n,"value":str(v)} for n,v in c.items()])
```

result:

```
[{'name': 'Jay', 'value': '8'}, {'name': 'roc', 'value': '11'}]
```

Comment: You might as well just use a `defaultdict`, since all you are doing is replacing `defaultdict(int)` with `Counter`. You aren't taking advantage of the main benefit of a `Counter`, which is to take a sequence of items and *count* related elements without explicitly iterating over the sequence.

Comment: @chepner you are right. In that case `Counter` is less interesting.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, without `collections.defaultdict`:

```
data = [{'name': 'Jay', 'value': '1'}, {'name': 'roc', 'value': '9'},
        {'name': 'Jay', 'value': '7'}, {'name': 'roc', 'value': '2'}]

result = {}
# concetrate
for element in data:
    result[element["name"]] = result.get(element["name"], 0) + int(element["value"])
# unpack
result = [{"name": element, "value": result[element]} for element in result]
# optionally, you can loop through result.items()
# you can, also, turn back result[elements] to str if needed

print(result)
# prints: [{'name': 'Jay', 'value': 8}, {'name': 'roc', 'value': 11}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve your question by using `groupby` from `itertools` module:

```
from itertools import groupby

a = [{'name':'Jay', 'value':'1'},{'name':'roc', 'value':'9'},{'name':'Jay', 'value':'7'},{'name':'roc', 'value':'2'}]
final = []
for k,v in groupby(sorted(a, key= lambda x: x["name"]), lambda x: x["name"]):
    final.append({"name": k, "value": str(sum(int(j["value"]) for j in list(v)))})

print(final)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'Jay', 'value': '8'}, {'name': 'roc', 'value': '11'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using *pandas*

```
names = [{'name':'Jay', 'value':'1'},{'name':'roc', 'value':'9'},{'name':'Jay', 'value':'7'},
         {'name':'roc', 'value':'2'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(names)
df['value'] = df['value'].astype(int)
group = df.groupby('name')['value'].sum().to_dict()
result = [{'name': name, 'value': value} for name, value in group.items()]
```

Which outputs:

```
[{'value': 8, 'name': 'Jay'}, {'value': 11, 'name': 'roc'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ld = [{'name':'Jay', 'value':'1'},{'name':'roc', 'value':'9'},{'name':'Jay', 'value':'7'},{'name':'roc', 'value':'2'}]

tempDict = {}
finalList = []


for d in ld:
  name = d['name']
  value = d['value']
  if name not in tempDict:
    tempDict[name] = 0
  tempDict[name] += int(value)

#tempDict => {'Jay': 8, 'roc': 11}

for name,value in tempDict.items():
  finalList.append({'name':name,'value':value})
print(finalList)  

# [{'name': 'Jay', 'value': 8}, {'name': 'roc', 'value': 11}]
```