# django - how to sum values of the same key?

Tags: django

I want to sum the value of the count key if the values of year_taken have duplicates, how can I do that?

[image]

so the output would look like this

{'year_taken': '2019-2020', 'count': 1}, {'year_taken': '2021-2022', 'count': 3}

Comment: You could do a for loop to sum them yourself. But I don't understand why django didn't do this for you already with `.values().annotate()`. Will you give an example of the raw table underlying this? Also, please post code as text rather than a screenshot.

Comment: can you show me how?

Comment: I just found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44183912/16933206)..

Comment: Rather than doing the summation using python you should use Subquery it will be faster.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/45547674

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField, OuterRef, Subquery

class SQCount(Subquery):
    output_field = IntegerField()
    template = f"(SELECT count(*) from (%(subquery)s)) _count)"

subquery_count = SQCount(Subject.objects.filter(year_taken=OuterRef("year_taken")))

queryset = Subject.objects.annotate(count=subquery_count).order_by("year_taken").distinct("year_taken").values("year_taken", "count")
```